# How to optimize UIImage scaling for fast scaling

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

People, i need your help.

Need optimizing scaling images on flow. I try two methods for scale image with save proportions, please inspect this code and say, how i can it optimize if you want/can:

```
// Draw image in rect (PNG 1000ms, JPG 834ms for 8 pictures)
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage
     scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:(CGSize)targetSize
            withInterpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality
{
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;

    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = (CGPoint){0.0, 0.0};

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {

            scaledWidth  = width * widthFactor;
            scaledHeight = height * widthFactor;

            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else {

            scaledWidth  = width * heightFactor;
            scaledHeight = height * heightFactor;

            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, YES, 1.0);

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("pro.idev.itux.projectNameHere", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL), ^{
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, quality);
        [sourceImage drawInRect:(CGRect){thumbnailPoint, {scaledWidth, scaledHeight}}];
    });

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}

// Draw CGImage in rect (PNG 1326ms, JPG 1026ms for 8 pictures)
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)sourceImage
scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:(CGSize)targetSize
       withInterpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality
{

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage);

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = (CGPoint){0.0, 0.0};

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize((CGSize){width, height}, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {

            scaledWidth  = width * widthFactor;
            scaledHeight = height * widthFactor;

            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else {

            scaledWidth  = width * heightFactor;
            scaledHeight = height * heightFactor;

            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, YES, 1.0);

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("pro.idev.itux.projectNameHere", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL), ^{
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, targetHeight);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, quality);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, (CGRect){thumbnailPoint, {scaledWidth, scaledHeight}}, sourceImage);
    });

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: You're leaking dispatch queues. You should hold onto the queue and release it when you're done. Plus, why are you creating your own queue and then dispatching synchronously to it? This will still block the caller, so you're not achieving any concurrency by doing this.

Comment: Ok, but how i can do this parallel ?

Comment: Step 1: Use a concurrent queue, not a serial queue. Step 2: Do it asynchronously, not synchronously. Step 3: Don't use UIKit at all for this, and especially not the current image context. Create your own CGBitmapContext from scratch, or use Core Image.

Comment: i want preload some pictures before load view... but if i use async i didn't see image after load view :( (because it will rescaling in "background")... Sorry, but if you have good example, please tell me link

Comment: When you're done scaling it, you throw the image back to the main queue to update your UI with it.

Comment: Thanks Peter, look here http://pastebin.com/Sv61QE2R Can you say how i speed up more... my app show table with miniatures of images, and show paging gallery with medium size... that is because i need rescale images, but i need more speed for loading my app and smooth listing images in gallery and tableview :(((((

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23017/discussion-between-itux-and-peter-hosey)

Comment: Run your code under Instruments's Time Profiler instrument and find out what's taking up most of the time. Then, either don't do that, do it later, or do it on a secondary thread (if you can).

Comment: Now i scale using Trevor methods, but more time is CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, transpose ? transposedRect : newRect, imageRef); function... :(

Comment: Now i found another way, without CG redraw, simply change CALayer size with calculated size for redraw, i get faster resize image and showing in UITableView :)